# How to get vocabulary items from the quizlet website?

Tags: c#

I am writing my own "version" of quizlet in C# as a console application and currently what I've done to get the learnset from quizlet on my program is copy it from the website, paste it into a text file and let my program convert it into a more usable format and save that locally. Basically what I want is a function that takes a string myLink and produces a text file with the learnset inside. The only step I'm stuck on is how to get the data from quizlet. What I've tried so far is "web scraping" I think it's called but it doesn't work with quizlet for some reason. I don't need the entire web code from "web scraping", only the learnset.

I know C# but I have no knowledge about connecting with a website and getting information so I also don't really know what to google. What would be a starting point for me? Even a thing to google would be helpful.

This is the code that I've tried which didn't work:

```
static async void WebsiteStuff()
{
    //clear console for new stuff
    Console.Clear();

    await GetWebsiteInfo();

    //stop it from ending
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task GetWebsiteInfo()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://quizlet.com/ch/795679237/test2-flash-cards/?funnelUUID=546d9a40-6e88-42ce-aac9-795f71a1bec5");
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

The error message was

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).'
```

Comment: WebClient? That's pretty dated. I think you are using a very old tutorial or so? You might want to look at HttpClient instead.

Comment: It looks like the site does not require any authorization to access the desired page. So, you can run fiddler / wireshark / whatever and then compare the content of a requests (headers / query params / body / etc) sent from the browser (where the page opens without problems) and from your C# code. Then modify the C# code to match the browser requests.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting blocked by Quizlet's servers apparently because they don't want you doing that. You should look to see if they have an API and get the data you want that way. And if they don't, find a similar product that does.